# jQuery: sending classname of fields of a form as an array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have multiple forms, and I want to send classnames of these [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) form's fields in an array to a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) server.

For example:

```
<form action="x.php">
    <input type="text" name="name_ajax" class="classname1" /></p>
    <input type="text" name="email_ajax" class="classname2" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to send `classname1` and `classname2` in an array via [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to `server.php` after loading the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var classes = {};

$('form input').each(function(index, element){
    classes[ $(element).attr('name') ] = $(element).attr('class');
});

$.post( 'path/to/php/script', $.param(classes) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
var classnames = [];
$("input").each(function(i, element) {
    classnames.push(element.getClass());
}

// send code to server using jQuery post here
```